# Mongoose text index search returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to query indexes, but I receive an empty array. I can't find what's wrong with my code. I used two methods to create the index: 1) VideoSchema.index() and 2) in the schema itself, both of them don't work. I checked the mongodb and it seems that indexes are created correctly, so I don't know what I do wrong.

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const VideoSchema = mongoose.Schema(
        {
            user: {
                type: mongoose.ObjectId,
                required: true,
                ref: "user",
            },
            title: {
                type: String,
                maxLength: 100,
                text: true,
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
                text: true,
            },
            publishDate: {
                type: Date,
            },
            views: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0,
            },
            likes: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0,
            },
            dislikes: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0,
            },
            comments: [
                {
                    type: mongoose.ObjectId,
                    ref: "comment",
                },
            ],
            urls: {
                video_url: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                },
                thumbnail_url: {
                    type: String,
                },
                preview_url: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                },
            },
            private: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: 0,
            },
            category: {
                type: String,
                default: "",
            },
            duration: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
            },
        },
        { timestamps: true }
    );
    
    // VideoSchema.index({ title: "text", description: "text" });
    
    // export model user with UserSchema
    module.exports = mongoose.model("video", VideoSchema);
```

The query:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();
    const Video = require("../model/Video");
    
    router.post("/", (req, res) => {
        const query = req.body.query;
        Video.find({ $text: { $search: query } }, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
            .sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
            .exec(function (error, results) {
                if (error) return res.status(400).send(error);
                res.status(200).json({ results });
            });
    });
    
    module.exports = router;
```

[image: MongoDB indexes]

Comment: @LuisOrbaiceta yes, I do. Maybe it's some mongoose problem?

Comment: if insted of query you search for everything, does it return any result?

Comment: yes, it is working, I tried both Video.find({ title: query }) and  Video.find()

Comment: Do you get any results if you pass an empty string to the $search field?

Comment: No, I don't get any.

Answer (score 1):

As you are fetching data from your Database it´s a good practice and makes the code clearer if you use the 'GET' method. If you do so, there is no need to add the score option to the query since V.4.4

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Video = require("../model/Video");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const query = req.query.YOUR_QUERY_PARAMETER;
    Video.find({ $text: { $search: query }})
        .sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
        .exec(function (error, results) {
            if (error) return res.status(400).send(error);
            res.status(200).json({ results });
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**If the problem persists:**
Try to add the wild card text indexing to see if the problem is within it as follows:

```
VideoSchema.index({'$**': 'text'});
```

If so, then drop the collection for a fresh start on the indexing and then append your text indexes like this:

```
VideoSchema.index({ title: "text", description: "text" });
```

Create new dummy items and then check again.

Make sure you read the exceptions shown in the MongoDB documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: I followed your guide. First I dropped the video and I tried the wild card and I got again the empty array. I checked the MongoDB if the index has been created and it was. Next, I dropped the videos again and tried the second option, but again I got the empty array. Maybe I do sth wrong in the query, the video that I upload every time is named 1600453498530_obs_recording and in the postman, I'm sending post request body JSON "query": "obs" or "query": "" and I always get an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I resolved the problem. I noticed that in the express js the 'query' keyword is used for 'get' request params, so I decided to change this variable to 'search', so now it is like underneath and it is working!

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const { search } = req.query;
    Video.find(
        { $text: { $search: search } },
        { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
    )
        .sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
        .exec(function (error, results) {
            if (error) return res.status(400).send(error);
            res.status(200).json({ results });
        });
});
```

But I've noticed that I'm getting only one video instead of two that contains the 'obs' in the title, so now I will need to deal with that.

Thank you so much for your time and effort!

Comment: No, no. I wanted to access the body post request and after reading your comment I check again how it behaves with the previous variable and now it is working with the previous req.body.query and I can't understand what exactly happened, it has to be a very subtle change somewhere which I can't notice.

Comment: Now I see that it is working like simple find, to get any results. I have 3 videos in the db with titles: 'obs short screen', 'obsstudio recording' and '1600287664895_obs_recording'. When I query obs I got only the first one, but I thought I would get all of them, because every video has 'obs' in the title. What's more when I query e.g. 'o' letter I get again an empty array although every video has 'o' letter in its title.